# robot test framework: how does Set Variable if work?

Tags: robotframework

I have following Keywords:

```
  App For Port    [Arguments]    ${app}
  # Try to launch one app on either port, continue if it fails on port 1 and launch it on port 2, record if it fails on both.
      ${returned_port}    Set Variable    ${1}
    : FOR    ${port_num}    IN    1    2
    \    ${returned_port}    Set Variable If    ${port_num} == 2    ${2}
    \    Check App Launch    ${app}    ${port_num}
    Return From Keyword    ${returned_port}
```

`${returned_port}    Set Variable    ${1}` works fine, `${returned_port}` is 1 after this line.

However, 
`${returned_port}    Set Variable If    ${port_num} == 2    ${2}` gives `${returned_port}` None value.

I'm really confused. How can I make it to set `${returned_port}` to 2??   Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See doc: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If
"The second value can also be omitted, in which case it has a default value None."
It means `Set Variable If` sets `${returned_port}` to `None` during first loop iteration.

Besides that you can simplify your code a bit:

```
App For Port
    [Arguments]    ${app}
    : FOR    ${port_num}    IN    1    2
    \    Check App Launch    ${app}    ${port_num}
```

... does the same. Does it? If you need to return value from the keyword without condition, just use `[Return]    ${var}`.

And one more - you could consider to use data-driven approach: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. But for the code simplification, since I need to return which port the `Check App Launch` actually uses to upper level keywords, so I guess I need to keep the code

Comment: Makes sense for me. I'm glad it helped.